# LG V60 Thin - Incoming calls sometimes show a square Answer, sometimes round Answer button? Why?

Tags: calls, lg

On my LG V60 Thin, Android 11, and I have Google Voice enabled, and Google owns my cell number.  (I expect it is related to this).

When someone calls me, and my phone is almost always on Mute ringer, I get two different interfaces for the incoming call.

Sometimes it is a square button, single touch answers.  This rings in my Bluetooth headset but not on the external speakers.

Sometimes it is a round button, press and hold to answer.  This is completely silent when this rings the phone.

Problem is, as far as I know, I cannot tell why the round or square app answers.  I would like to always use the square button to answer, but cannot figure out where this might be controlled.

(I checked. If I call the real phones # that Google Voice redirects too, it comes the same as calling the Google Voice #. So I expect this is somehow related, but not this easy an answer).

Comment: Maybe a bug wiith Google Dialer?

Comment: Or the LG Skin?  Thus the question, if anyone else has seen this, knows what it might be. Or even what the different round/square buttons indicate.